# How to prove that given polygonal chain of line segments is greater than a given straight line?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles

The problem is from my textbook, the topic is "*A midline of a triangle*":

> Given a triangle $ABC$ and points $D$ and $E$ such that $∠ADB =∠BEC = 90°$. Prove that $DE ≤ \frac{1}{2}P \triangle ABC$.

[image: The problem's figure]

**My solution**:

As it's known, a median of a right triangle, lowered from a right angle, is equal to a half of a hypotenuse, so let's lower two medians: 
$DK$ onto $AB$ => $DK=AK=KB$

 and 
$EM$ onto $BC$ => $EM=BM=MC$.

$KM$ itself is a midline of $\triangle ABC$, so:
$\frac{1}{2}P \triangle ABC$ = $\frac{1}{2}AC + AK + KC$ = $DK + KM + ME$

What I'm left with is a polygonal chain of the $DK$, $KM$ and $ME$ line segments and I'm not sure how to finish the proof. "*Each side of a triangle is smaller than the sum of its two other sides.*", as my textbook states, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Look at triangles $DKM$ and then $DME$ maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: InequalityPart1]

Instead of attacking the question posed in OP’s problem statement, let us consider $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1\it{a}}\space$ given above. There, we show that segment $UV$ is shorter than or equal the length of the segment $GH$.

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 1\it{a}}\space$ shows two circles intersecting at $S$ and $T$. The red circle has its center at $P$ while that of the green circle is at $Q$. Line drawn through $P$ and $Q$ cut the two circles at $G$ and $H$. The point $W$ lies on $GH$ and a line through $W$ cut the circles at $U$ and $V$.

We apply the triangle inequality to the triangle $UPW$ to obtain,
$$WU \le PU+PW=WG.\tag{1}$$

Similarly, we can prove that,
$$WV\le WH.\tag{2}$$

We can use (1) and (2) to show that,
$$WU+WV\le WG+WH \qquad\rightarrow\qquad UV\le GH.$$

Now, we apply this to the configuration depicted in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1\it{b}}\space$ to show that the inequality mentioned in your problem statement holds.

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 1\it{b}}\space$ is an extended version of OP’s sketch, in which we have added two circles with centers at the midpoints $K$ and $M$ of the sides $BA$ and $BC$ respectively. Besides, the line segment $GH$, which passes through $K$ and $M$, is also included and this line is going to play a vital role in our proof of OP’s inequality. Let’s determine the length of $GH$ as described below. For brevity we denote the semiperimeter of $\triangle ABC$ by $s$.
$$GH=GK+KM+MH=BK+\dfrac{AC}{2}+BM=\dfrac{BA}{2}+\dfrac{AC}{2}+\dfrac{BC}{2}=s$$

According to the lemma, which we have already proven, we have,
$$DE\le GH=s.$$

The equality holds when $D$ and $E$ coincide with $G$ and $H$ respectively.

The story does not end here. In order to prove that the mentioned inequality is valid in general, we need to prove another version of the lemma (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2\it{a}}$) and apply it to the corresponding scenario of the inequality (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2\it{b}}$) to show that it holds.

[image: InequalityPart2]

Comment: Thank you, very impressive proof. Yeah, I was about to prove it myself, but what confused me is that I didn't consider two possible cases: with intersection and without. Your proof is way more rigorous than mine, yet 100% correct. I'd also add here("We apply the triangle inequality to the triangle UPW") that UPW can as well be a straight line, not only a triangle, otherwise we'd have strict inequality: WU<PU+PW=WG. Thanks again!

Comment: @curioushuman Happy to hear from you. We removed that annoying little note from our answer.